# how to model this relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am starting a new 3.2 rails (would ideally like to be on MySQL) project that is focused on selling different types of vehicles. We are starting by modeling cars, motorcycles, and trailers. I am thinking of having a Vehicle class that handles the common aspects (such as is_enabled ) and then having a profile for each of the subclassed (like has_one: motorcycle_profile).

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :is_enabled, :year #
end

class Motorcyle < Vehicle
  has_one :motorcycle_profile  
end

class MotorcyleProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :front_tire # something motorcycle specific
end

...
```

Does this sound like a reasonable approach? Would STI help with this or that more problems than it's worth?

thx for help

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this kind of webshop software is that you seldomly need one kind of products to behave different than other kind of products. After all, they can all be bought in pretty much the same way with a price, a product code and some photos. However, you may want to include different attributes on different kind of products.

For instance, a fuel type attribute on a bike makes little sense, while a pedal attribute on a car is equally pointless. Instead of creating different ActiveRecord models to shoehorn your varying attributes into different tables, I think you should consider putting the shared attributes in ordinary columns and then put the customized data into a hash store, which is supported by Rails 4 and Postgres.

It basically allows you to have a different set of attributes for each individual product record.

Comment: thx Niels, I get where you're going with that concept. Honestly, I haven't made the jump to Rails 4 and Postgres (would prob do 3.2 and MySQL). I will look into these suggestions though. I would be a little concerned though about searching, scopes, etc with it in a hash store. Also, it might be a bit opaque for new developers. But those things change over time.

Comment: Postgres provides support for querying individual custom attributes.